# Why injection does not work in child class?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a singltone class:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Services {
    public Service1 = new Service1();
}
```

**Service1** whole class is:

```
import { HttpRequests } from './http';
import { RepositoryModel } from './repository';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    export class Service1 {
        public http: HttpRequests;
        public repositoryModel: RepositoryModel;

        constructor(private httpClient?: HttpClient) {
            console.log(httpClient);
            this.repositoryModel = new RepositoryModel();
            this.http = new HttpRequests(this.httpClient, this.repositoryModel);
        }
    }
```

Why I get `undefined` on line: `console.log(httpClient);` though I have `httpClientModule` in `app.module`?

Using is:

```
 constructor(private services: Services) {}
```

Comment: Post all imports as well, please.

Comment: Added all imports

Comment: The question is, why are you double abstracting your service? The undefined makes sense, you’re not passing in the client inside new Service1()..

Comment: I tried to create repository off all services, because they have the same structure, and they names like Service1, Service 2

Comment: You are not letting handle Angular dependency injection management when you are intantiating object on your own. You can't use it like this because as I said, it is not Angular who are creating an object. What structure your services have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you create Service1 by contructor instead of by bean creatation.
You have 2 solutions. Inject `HttpClient` into Service1 by contructor from Service:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Services {

    private service1: Service1;

    constructor(private httpClient?: HttpClient){
        this.service1 = new Service1(this.httpClient);
    }
}
```

or change Service1 as bean

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Services {

constructor(private service1: Service1) {
    }
}


import { HttpRequests } from './http';
import { RepositoryModel } from './repository';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Service1 {
public http: HttpRequests;
public repositoryModel: RepositoryModel;

constructor(private httpClient?: HttpClient) {
    console.log(httpClient);
    this.repositoryModel = new RepositoryModel();
    this.http = new HttpRequests(this.httpClient, this.repositoryModel);
    }
}
```